# access images from remote server on ie

Tags: internet-explorer

I use the following code to access images from a remote web server, which works fine in all browsers except IE(using IE 8). Is there a if IE code I can use for the image to display if the web visitor is using IE?

the code:`<html> bla bla <img src="https://remotewebserver/somedir
/someimage.png"> </html>`

Image displayed in other browsers except IE8

Comment: why are you using a https connection?

Comment: The remote server is running apache with ssl. Like I mentioned before Firefox and other browsers work fine. Only IE 8 is doesn't display the image

Comment: Are you using mixed content? (ie. some content is retrieved through https while the rest is retrieved through http) It could be that IE 8 is simply blocking access to the nonsecure data...

Comment: More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)